# C# .CreationTime/.AddHours Issue

Tags: c#

I created a console application that checks the dates on SQL backup files.  One of the folders appears to have the backup copied in, so the Modified Date is earlier than the Created date, so I am trying to check by creation date `(file.CreationTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)`.  However when I try to create a variable to check `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)` the variable is not getting set.  Also, with a file that has a creation date of 10/31/2013 11:30 AM, it is failing the check I mentioned above which does not make any sense to me.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with this code?  I swear I have had to write it for a similar situation before and it worked.

```
//Is it more than 24 hours old?  If dt.DayofWeek.ToString() = "Monday", check for 72 hours. 
        if (dt == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            checkHours = fiFo.CreationTime> DateTime.Now.AddHours(-72);
        }
        else
        {
            checkHours = fiFo.CreationTime> DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24);
        }
```

Above is what is working on most of the sites.  But with the one that gets copied over so the CreationTime is the accurate datetime, it will be false even though I know the date is correct and should return true.

Comment: You'll have to show some code to have any hope of somebody being able to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, edited the initial post.  If checkHours is false we send an e-mail notifying us that a backup is old.  For some reason when I use fiFo.CreationTime it seems to think it's older every time, even with a CreationTime of what I mentioned above.

Comment: Just to be sure; did you step over the code and looked at the actual date in `fiFo.LastWriteTime`?

Comment: Yeah, I should've changed the code, I'm using CreationTime for the one I'm having an issue with and the CreationTime is correctly showing as today.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use <= (to determine more than X hours old) because > says 'The last write time is less than 24 hours old' but <= says 'The last write time is greater than or equal to 24 hours old.'

Time is funny like that.

Comment: `checkHours = fiFo.CreationTime> DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)` says the file was created after 24 hours ago.  The OP says `10/31/2013 11:30 AM` should pass the check.  Your solution makes it fail.

Comment: @Harrison - Nope.  More than 24 hours old you would need a <= in that statement.  Your use of > says it's less than 24 hours old.  Think about it, greater than (now - 24 hours) vs. less than or equal to (now - 24 hours).

Comment: Right. `Your use of > says it's less than 24 hours old` Exactly...The OP says that `10/31/2013 11:30 AM` should pass...aka less than 24 hours old

Comment: His code comment says "Is it more than 24 hours old?"  So what exactly are we determining here "Less than 24 hours old?" or "More than 24 hours old?"

Comment: Good point on the code comments.  I still don't think this is what the OP is asking for

Comment: Usually the backups are made at around 8-12 at night.  So a typical backup would be created around let's say 10:00PM.  The backup checker probably runs around 2-4AM depending on the different backup times.  So let's say at the latest, our check happens at 4:00AM.  So with the backup at 10:00PM, 4:00AM - 24 hours would make 10:00PM > 4:00 AM (the previous day, before the file's 10:00PM) valid, correct?  That is how it is supposed to work.  So if the backup is more than 24 hours old, we need to get a fresh backup.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion.  If the file's creation or write time is not greater than 24 hours ago, then it is more than a day old.